# Custom bool icons for Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a `bool` column in DjangoAdmin which shows the red and green icons like so:

[image]

The client it's for however is requesting blue and yellow icons since it's what they've been using for years. Is there any way to replace these and use my own custom icons?

Comment: these icons are placed in `STATIC_ROOT/admin/img/icon-yes.svg` and `STATIC_ROOT/admin/img/icon-no.svg`, you can change them with your preferred ones. you can also override them in the static folder to preserve the customization for future `collectstatic`s

Comment: Is it possible to override these on a per model basis? The dev team still uses the admin site as well so I think it would be jarring for them for all bool icons to be blue and yellow

Comment: yes, but it's a fair bit of code to implement it; there are several ways to do it, on top of my head, you can have a customized set of icons and templates for your customer, and use the default one for your dev team, and serve them to client based on their role, group, username, ...; this should help [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

Comment: Got it Sajad, thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct

Comment: you're welcome Lorenzo

Comment: BTW, for anyone who's puzzled by the cosmetic choice that seems to imply that "false = bad", it's not likely to be changed in the near future: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are placed in `STATIC_ROOT/admin/img/icon-yes.svg` and `STATIC_ROOT/admin/img/icon-no.svg`, you can change them with your preferred ones. you can also override them in the static folder to preserve the customization for future `collectstatic`s.
If you want to have customized icons just for a subset of users, you can have two versions of the template, the default and the customized, and then serve them to client based on their role, group, username, ... .

more information is available here: [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)